# Why is the array empty in page render, but after the render array is full?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zustand

Why is the array empty in page render, but after the render array is full?
I have an error with empty array `"transactions": Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'balance').` I see in the console that after render the array has objects at the response Page (`const currentBalance`)
I use zustand like state manager.

```
const currentBalance = (set, get) => ({
    transactions: [],
    getBalance: async () => {
        await getDocs(colBal)
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let transactions = []
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    transactions.push({...doc.data(), id:doc.id})
                    set({transactions: transactions})
                })
                console.log(transactions)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message)
            })
    },
```

why is "transactions" array empty in the Header page?

```
const Header = () => {
    const getBalance = useStore((state) => state.getBalance)
    const transactions = useStore((state) => state.transactions)

    useEffect(() => {
        getBalance()
    }, [getBalance]);

    console.log(transactions)
```

I'm expecting to see a non empty array "transactions" at the Header page.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state atom in the `forEach` loop; do it afterwards instead.

Also,

- don't mix and match `.then()` with `async`/`await`.
- `map` is preferable when you'd be looping over an array with `forEach` just to transform each and every member to something else.

```
const currentBalance = (set, get) => ({
  transactions: [],
  async getBalance() {
    const snapshot = await getDocs(colBal);
    const transactions = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));
    set({transactions});
  }
});
```

Comment: Your advice didn't help me. I think the problem is in the rendering of the Header component. In the Header component I see empty array "transactions" in the rendering.

Comment: problem was in the mapping of transactions. sorry for your time. thank you